# How to create PRJ file for selfmade polygons in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile

I have made a floodmap in ArcMap 10.4 and I would like to export it to ArcGIS Online. I tried, but it keeps saying ....shp can't be exported because it has no prj file. How do I create a prj file from normal shapefiles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .prj file will be created automatically if you define your shapefile's coordinate system, either by

- opening its properties in ArcCatalog/Catalog window: Double-click the shapefile to open its properties, click the 'XY Coordinate System' tab and select the appropriate coordinate system.

[image]

- or by using the [Define Projection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/define-projection.htm) tool.

Both methods require you to know what the coordinate system of your shapefile is, of course.

Comment: and of course, assume that the user knows what coordinate system the data is in!