# Opening PRJ file in text editor?

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile

I have some prj files (Only prj) but don't know how to open them, I tried ArcMap but have no clue. I understand prj is a part of a shapefile, but I don't have any other files than these.

Answer (score 18):

Right click and open with a text editor like notepad (or Notepad ++).
It's not a GIS layer, just some projection metadata on your layer.

A shapefile is made of severall files with some mandatory. The prj is not one of them. You'll need to ask for the mandatory ones... :

> **Mandatory files**
>
> - **.shp** — shape format; the feature geometry itself
> - **.shx** — shape index format; a positional index of the feature geometry to allow seeking forwards and backwards quickly
> - **.dbf** — attribute format; columnar attributes for each shape, in dBase IV format
>
> **Other files**
>
> - *.prj — projection format; the coordinate system and projection information, a plain text file describing the projection using
>   well-known text format*
> - .sbn and .sbx — a spatial index of the features
> - .fbn and .fbx — a spatial index of the features that are read-only
> - .ain and .aih — an attribute index of the active fields in a table
> - .ixs — a geocoding index for read-write datasets
> - .mxs — a geocoding index for read-write datasets (ODB format)
> - .atx — an attribute index for the .dbf file in the form of shapefile.columnname.atx (ArcGIS 8 and later)
> - .shp.xml — geospatial metadata in XML format, such as ISO 19115 or other XML schema
> - .cpg — used to specify the code page (only for .dbf) for identifying the character encoding to be used
> - .qix — an alternative quadtree spatial index used by MapServer and GDAL/OGR software

Source : [Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile)

Comment: This is one reason plain text is superior to binary whenever it's practical.

Comment: if i open it with notepad it says:
ÂH;V ŒÄ? tTà‹«?Œ´cÂHÛ?øâê e?.qê÷Üç?¶›åIdŠ?š™™™™™é?©ÀW?èØ?ð¹%Nýžë?/®~ÐQé?ê÷Ü§~ß?Ó°Ý,O"ë?
„‘v¬@¸?ë øâê?AiÇ
„Á?è¨ÀW?à?2

Comment: That is very strange, it doesn't look like a prj file to me. Could you upload on of your files on some website for us to test it ? It shouldn't be a heavy file. What's it's size by the way ?

Comment: Here is the link for it: https://www.file-upload.net/download-12931703/PrjFile.zip.html
Its size is 1 kb

Comment: Could you rather use https://wetransfer.com/ ? The link you gave me links out to a suspicious exe file of 500Kb or to some adverts... Many thanks.

Comment: You have to press the blue "Download" button, then a new tab open and then press the blue button again and it will download automatically?

Comment: Thanks it worked. I've no idea what this thing is, but it's sure not a prj file. You should definitively ask for other files. Your prj should look like : PROJCS["British_National_Grid",GEOGCS["GCS_OSGB_1936",DATUM["D_OSGB_1936",SPHEROID["Airy_1830",6377563.396,299.3249646]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",400000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-100000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-2.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.999601272],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",49.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]].

Comment: But it is a prj file or something like that. Because i have a game and there is a map of many countrys. So if i click on germany, it shows the map of germany and i can set a point on the map. And the prj file tells this game "Hey, the upper limit of the map 55 N And in the south its 47 N". So every country has a prj file for itself.

Comment: And i got no idea, how can i create a prj file or coordinate system in ArcGis, the manual is to complicated for me.

Comment: This is definitively NOT A PRJ FILE FOR ARCGIS... nor any GIS known to me. Maybe the software / game you are talking about and that you didn't mention has it's own prj file format but I doubt you will find the info here if it's not a GIS software. If you have a question regarding a game or another software, please be precise in your question.  I answered your question regarding arcgis desktop. Please ask another question if you need to create a prj file for your data or a specific software.

Comment: Yes, then my question is , how can be a prj file created similar to mine? So that is shows a coordinate system for a country. Maybe the prj you send me works,if i fill in the right numbers. What would them be for Germany?

Comment: You should create a new question, and maybe look if the question hasn't been asked before (example : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219334/how-to-create-prj-file-for-selfmade-polygons-in-arcmap or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237770/what-is-a-projection-for-germany-that-preserves-distance).